# Select multiple divs and the same time, and let user close them

Tags: jquery

I want a function in jQuery that lets you to open multiple divs at the same time, without the previous one closing. The visitors of the website will press them to open them, and then press them again to close them.

Comment: Show us some code of what you've tried. It's just a matter of `$('div.'+name).show()` within a `$(name).click()` event.

Comment: @LaughDonor - I have been using http://stackoverflow.com/a/16868488/1802987 a long time, but that one closes the div when it opens a new one, and i have been searching on the internet for like 30 minutes on this without any result.

Comment: You should try to understand what the code is doing as you implement it. That's what makes a better coder. The Javascript in that example you gave is a complex and terrible way to implement what you want.

Comment: @LaughDonor - Probably. That's why i asked about a code that can do the thing i wanted help with. I'm totally new to jQuery, i want to learn :)

Comment: Check this fiddle I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/FmdP4/

Comment: @LaughDonor - How do i add a class to the selected li's? Example if i want the usual color to be gray, and the selected ones to be black? Thanks!

Comment: It's a simple `$(this).addClass("nameofclass")` and `$(this).removeClass("nameofclass")` where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmdP4/) so you can pick it apart with the things you'll need.

First, you'll need to basically set up some `onclick` event handlers for the "buttons" you'd like to use to toggle those divs.

```
$('.types li').click( functionName );
```

Then in that function, you'll have to grab a specific identifier for the corresponding `div` you want to toggle. `t` is the event handler that's called back:

`t.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase()` will match the "button's" inner text and convert to lowercase.

Then, since that value is a valid **id**, we create a jQuery selector for it by prepending the `#` and [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) it's visibility.

```
$(selectorId).toggle();
```

Voilà! If you need more details, check out the jQuery Docs. If you want to have animations, best to have CSS transitions do it for you, and use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).